# minipage's \textwidth is actually slightly wider and indented, even with the parskip package. Why?

Tags: margins, minipage, width, parskip

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}




\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]


\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
}


\end{document}
```

Why is there still a small indent and why is the `minipage` frame wider than the overall frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some spurious spaces in your `\fbox` which causes the opening and closing spacing issues (see [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)). Also, the width of the text block should be reduced by the width of the `\fbox`'s rule (`\fboxrule`) and the box gap (`\fboxsep`) *twice* (once for each side).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

% Note the use of '%' here...
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used `\linewidth` although in this particular instance you can use `\textwidth` as well. `\linewidth` would be appropriate in general as it may change based on whether or not the margins change (as it does inside a list).

Answer (score 2):

You want to take into account the `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule` parameters. Here's a new environment `fminipage` that shares all syntax with `minipage` and does the computation by itself.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% a handy function
\cs_set_eq:NN \dimeval \dim_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newsavebox{\fminipagebox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{fminipage}{O{c}oO{#1}m}
 {%
  \begin{lrbox}{\fminipagebox}
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\begin{minipage}[#1]{\dimeval{#4-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}}}
    {\begin{minipage}[#1][#2][#3]{\dimeval{#4-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}}}
 }
 {%
  \end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\fminipagebox}}%
 }


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-4]


\begin{fminipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[1][5-7]
\end{fminipage}

\begin{center}
x\begin{fminipage}[t][4cm][s]{4cm}
\lipsum[2][1]

\vfill

\lipsum[2][2]
\end{fminipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]